# Instantiate prefab randomly but not in already genrated position

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to generate bubble randomly in my screen.When bubble is generated in one place then other bubble can not generated near of its radius 1 area. means bubbles can not collide or triggered with any other bubbles.

How can i do it ?

```
public void GenerateBubble ()
        {
                newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-7, 7);
                newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-3, 3);
                bubbleClone = (GameObject)Instantiate (bubblePrefab, new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                UIManager.instance.ChangeBubbleSprite (bubbleClone);
                bubbleList.Add (bubbleClone);
                if (bubblePosList.Contains (bubbleClone.transform.position)) {
                    bubbleClone.transform.position=new Vector3(Random.Range (-7,7),Random.Range (-3,3),0);
                }
                bubblePosList.Add (bubbleClone.transform.position);
                bubbleClone.transform.parent = UIManager.instance.CurrentLevel.transform;
                GLOBALS.bubbleCounter++;
        }
```

In this my code every bubble is generated in different position but it can collide with other bubble means i want to generate new bubble not same position as well as it can not collide also.
My bubble colliders's radius is 1.

Comment: I don't think people are going to want to do this for you, unless you have demonstrated that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first. What have you tried? Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Found Answer :

```
    public List<GameObject> bubbleList = new List<GameObject> ();
    private int newBubbleXPos;
    private int newBubbleYPos;

public void GenerateBubble ()
    {
        bool locationInvaild = true;
        while (locationInvaild) {
            newBubbleXPos = Random.Range (-8, 8);
            newBubbleYPos = Random.Range (-4, 4);
            currentPosition = new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0);
            locationInvaild = false;
            for (int i=0; i<bubbleList.Count; i++) {
                if (Vector3.Distance (bubbleList [i].transform.position, currentPosition) < 2.5f * radius) {
                    locationInvaild = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bubbleClone = Instantiate (bubblePrefab, new Vector3 (newBubbleXPos, newBubbleYPos, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bubbleList.Add (bubbleClone);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [a packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem). Calculating a position where a bubble doesn't collide with any other bubble or boundaries might get a bit difficult (especially if there are a lot of bubbles and little space).

Thus I would recommend first looking for easier approaches such as

- Divide the area to a grid where one cell is a little bit bigger than the bubble. Then first randomly choose a cell and then add a little random variation to the position. If you randomly choose an already used cell, just take the next available cell.
- Take advantage of physics: when you create a new bubble, set it mass low (such as 1) and after a short while change it mass big (such as 1000). Also freeze their rotations and add collider components. This way the new bubble will have to "find" new space since two physical objects can not overlap and the one with lower mass will move.
- If there are only few bubbles, you could just randomly create a new position until it doesn't collide with any other bubble.

Also the positions could probably be pre-calculated so there is no need to do it runtime.